# Failed to launch IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool via CoreSimulator spawn Issue on XCode 9.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on a basic app and every time I try to run the project I get this warning:

Failed to launch IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool via CoreSimulator spawn

I've tried everything I could find on the internet but no one has been able to find the right answer for me.

- I've tried cleaning the project.
- Removing the assets folder, cleaning the project, then adding the
  assets folder again and trying to build.
- I've tried to clean the project, restart XCode, then run the app.

I'm all out of ideas on what to do and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Thank you in advance for any ideas you might have!!

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103670

Seems to be an issue if you're using Xcode 10 and < 10.14 Mojave beta.